# OAuth2 error: CSRF Detected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth

I'm using the ominauth-google-oauth2 gem in Rails. I Can't say that this is a bug but I am stumped on how to solve it. I've written a super simple Rails program to verify the problem. I am following [these instructions](https://medium.com/@ajayramesh/social-login-with-omniauth-and-rails-5-0-ad2bbd2a998e).

It seems that when I attempt to login to my gmail.com account, when I have other google oauth enabled accounts, I get this exception:

```
OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError at /auth/google_oauth2/callback
csrf_detected | CSRF detected
```

Here's the top of the stack trace:

```
Started GET "/auth/google_oauth2/callback?state=732fc603c628199503f01781639123426e7fbfa874a36a4a&code=4%2FF2VhN4EQfwYxr5cAmyp5S9sufuFMLP9Rpl-o85zWyyE" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-10-16 12:01:03 -0400
I, [2017-10-16T12:01:03.814169 #58394]  INFO -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Callback phase initiated.
E, [2017-10-16T12:01:03.814832 #58394] ERROR -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Authentication failure! csrf_detected: OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError, csrf_detected | CSRF detected
E, [2017-10-16T12:01:03.815656 #58394] ERROR -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError, csrf_detected | CSRF detected

OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError - csrf_detected | CSRF detected:
  omniauth (1.7.1) lib/omniauth/failure_endpoint.rb:25:in `raise_out!'
  omniauth (1.7.1) lib/omniauth/failure_endpoint.rb:20:in `call'
  omniauth (1.7.1) lib/omniauth/failure_endpoint.rb:12:in `call'
  omniauth (1.7.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:486:in `fail!'
  omniauth-oauth2 (1.4.0) lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth2.rb:71:in `callback_phase'
  omniauth (1.7.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:236:in `callback_call'
  omniauth (1.7.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:188:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.7.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:168:in `call'
  omniauth (1.7.1) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:63:in `call'
  rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
```

Here are all the relevant code snippets:

## initializers/omniauth.rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2,
  "redacted",
  "redacted"
end
```

## routes.rb

```
get 'login', to: redirect('/auth/google_oauth2'), as: 'login'
get 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'logout'
get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
get 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
get 'home', to: 'home#show'
get 'me', to: 'me#show', as: 'me'
```

## views/home/show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Sign in with Google", "/auth/google_oauth2", id: "sign_in" %>
```

## application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  helper_method :current_user

  def authenticate
    redirect_to :login unless user_signed_in?
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  def user_signed_in?
    # converts current_user to a boolean by negating the negation
    !current_user.nil?
  end
end
```

## sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.find_or_create_from_auth_hash(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
    redirect_to :me
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

- I run the server with rails server -p 3000
- I access the page with http://localhost:3000
- This displays the page with the login button, which I press
- This displays a list of all my possible google logins (I think there are 4)
- I click on one of them, and I get the following exception: 

  OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError at /auth/google_oauth2/callback
  csrf_detected | CSRF detected

Stack trace is attached:

[image: screen shot 2017-10-15 at 10 44 21 am]

Comment: can you copy just the lines of the stacktrace that show the request arriving at the server? Presumably it shows a PUT or POST request, but it would be helpful to confirm.

Comment: I put it into the main message

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, missed it in all the info you provided. Have you seen this potential cause: https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-oauth2/issues/58#issuecomment-49590041